# Git: reduce the size of `.git/lfs/`

Tags: git, git-lfs

I use git-lfs to track large files, the setup is:

```
.
├── ...
├── ...
├── large-files
├── ...
├── ...
└── .git
```

where an external storage is mounted on `large-files`, and all large files go here.

The problem with this setup is, there is a `.git/lfs` directory, which uses the same amount disk spaces as the `large-files`, since I will never delete from `large-files`, and my SSD, where the working tree resides, has smaller capacity than the external storage, `.git/lfs` will outgrow my SSD's capacity.

Is there a way to reduce the size of this `.git/lfs` without moving it to an external storage? (putting `.git` or the entire working tree to the external storage is not an option, because the external storage is not always available)

Comment: Are you using `git-lfs`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.git/lfs` is the local cache directory for [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/), Git Large File Storage. It keeps the repository size down by storing the history of large files in cloud storage instead of in local history.

`.git/lfs` will not grow indefinitely. It's normal for `git-lfs` to cache "recent" versions of large files there. You can run [`git lfs prune`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-prune.1.ronn) to have it prune the cache, and you can configure how much it prunes with `lfs.pruneoffsetdays` and [`lfs.fetchrecent`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-fetch.1.ronn).

You can also put this directory elsewhere by [changing `lfs.storage`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-config.5.ronn).